# jquery animate function initialize the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
$(element).delay(2000).animate(
    {
        scale: 1,
    },
    {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function(now) {
            scaleVal = now;
            $(element).attr("transform", "translate(" + centerX + " " + centerY + ") scale(" + scaleVal + ") translate(" + (-centerX) + " " + (-centerY) + ")");
        }
    }
);
```

Now the scale value starts from 0 and ends up in 1 but instead of this I want to start from 0.5 and ends up in 1.

How can I initialize the scale value in animate function?

Comment: @eclanrs that is not CSS. it is attribute of an element. how can i ?

Answer (score -2):

you need to use `css` function

```
$(ele).css('scale', 0.5).animate({scale:1});
```

Comment: that is not a css. that is attribute of an element.so please change your code.

Comment: @SivaRajini if you want to set attribute use `attr` but AFAIK jQuery animate work only with CSS properies.

Comment: we can do animations for attributes too. animation working fine for me but scale value  always starts from 0.i want to starts from  0.5 or 0.6