# jquery animate step function with attribute value initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Please refer below animation code.

```
$(element).delay(2000).animate({
    scale: 1,
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function (now) {
        scaleVal = now;
        $(element).attr("transform", "translate(" + centerX + " " + centerY + ") scale(" + scaleVal + ") translate(" + (-centerX) + " " + (-centerY) + ")");
    }
});
```

scale is attribute of an element. scale value always starts from  0 and end up in 1. i want scale value starts from 0.5 and goes up to 1.

In step function scale always starts from 0.

**Need : scale value maximum is 1 and starts from 0.5 instead of 0.**

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery animate function initialize the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037687/jquery-animate-function-initialize-the-value)

Comment: @eclanrs: there is no solution provided in that link.am using attribute not a css of an element.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery use [`Tween.propHooks`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L424) to get/set properties in animation. The non-CSS property `scale` will be treated as a property binded to the DOM element that is being animated on. So you can set the initial value of the `scale` property before animation.

```js
$(element).each(function () { this.scale = 0.5; }).delay(2000).animate({
    scale: 1,
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function (now) {
        scaleVal = now;
        $(element).attr("transform", "translate(" + centerX + " " + centerY + ") scale(" + scaleVal + ") translate(" + (-centerX) + " " + (-centerY) + ")");
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lescb/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You may also use second argument of the step function, which is a reference to the jQuery.fx object. Among other it has "start" property that specifies first value of the animated property (it also has 'end' for the last value and 'prop' to specify property being animated)

Also you should set css transform of the animated element to be 0.5 at the beginning, so that it won't be set from 0 to 0.5 abruptly when animation starts, and you should use .css method to do this, not .attr, as its not element's attribute, but css3 property.

```
$(element).css("transform","scale(0.5)").delay(2000).animate({
    scale: 1,
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function (now, fx) {
        scaleVal = now;
        fx.start = 0.5;  
        $(element).css("transform", "scale(" + scaleVal + ")");
    }
});
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/4t4Lg/2)

also, when you use "translate" method for css transformation, you should set comma between x and y values
`translate(" + centerX + ", " + centerY + ")`

Comment: fx.start is the real answer because sometimes you cannot set the DOM property of the element. Thanks :)